# Xinetd , vncserver memory requirement

Tags: linux, memory, vnc, xinetd, window-managers

I am installing the following on a low memory system:

```
vnc4server xinetd xterm openbox obconf
```

I will only occasionally be logging into the vncs for some admin work. My question is:

1) Does xinetd take memory / cpu even when vncserver is not running?
 If so, can I "run" xinetd on demand (how)? And if no, any idea how much memory 
it will take when vncserver is not running?

2) Does vncserver take substantial memory when no clients are connected?

3) Do openbox/obconf take memory when vncserver is running but no client are connected?

4) Do openbox/obconf take memory when no vncserver is running?

thanks

JP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xinetd is the process that does the on demand service and runs all the time.  It waits for network connections and then starts a process to service them.  It requires only a tiny bit of system resources.

The VNC server or the programs displaying on it will use memory if they're running, but if they're not actively doing anything it will be swapped at to disk until needed.  A VNC server can active even without clients connected if the programs displaying on it are changing their display.